# Discord Bot embed

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

Im having a little trouble embeding this for a discord bot i tried some thing but none seem to work.

```
import os


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, *, ipaddr: str = '1.3.3.7'):
    ip_list = [ipaddr]    
    for ip in ip_list:
        response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
        if "Received = 4" in response:
            await ctx.send(f"UP {ip} / Ping Successful")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"DOWN {ip} / Ping Unsuccessful")
```

NEVER MIND ISSUE WAS FIXED I JUST DID THIS BELOW

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, *, ipaddr: str = '1.3.3.7'):
    ip_list = [ipaddr]  

    embed = discord.Embed(title='Ping Info:', color=0xFF0000)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    
    for ip in ip_list:
        response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
        if "Received = 4" in response:
            embed.add_field(name=f"{ip} is UP", value="Ping Successful", inline=False)
        else:
            embed.add_field(name=f"{ip} is DOWN", value="Ping Unsuccessful", inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? or where are you building the embed?

Comment: the for loop seems useless since ip_list is always gonna just have a single item. consider removing the list and instead of `*, ipaddr`, use `*ipaddr` then just loop through `ipaddr`. this will allow you to pass multiple IP addresses separated by spaces

Comment: And what are those things that you tried? If you don't provide your attempted code then we can't help you fix it.